# Некорректная работа с устройством через COM-порт

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com-порт

Есть сторонняя программа, которая соединяется с COM-портом и посылает туда один символ. Я пишу примерно такую же, посылающую то же самое. Но моей программе возвращается ошибка работы с COM.

Сделал мониторинг передачи. Мои программа посылает абсолютно идентичный запрос.

Могу предположить, что внешнее устройство не успевает «понять», что к нему подключилась программа, и поэтому возвращает ошибку. Пытался организовать задержку перед передачей с помощью вызова функции `Sleep()`, однако записи в COM-порт при этом не происходит, будто устройство «порвало» связь.

В чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?

Тип приложения — консольное на VC++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мало просто послать символ. Нужно ещё правильно выставить настройки порта. А их много. Можно просто не угадать скорость или кол-во стопбитов и все, ничего не будет работать.

Поэтому рекомендую простую утилитку [portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) - она не просто покажет весь обмен, а и как именно нужно настроить порт. В любом случае можно будет сравнить два лога и найти разницу.